# Raw content of DOMElement::innerHTML

Tags: php, domdocument

How, in PHP, I can get the raw content of `DOMElement`, like JS `innerHTML` does?

I tried with `saveHTML()` or `saveXML()` iterating over each `childNodes` to simulate `innerHTML`, but it replaced code like turning `<br />` to `<br>` or `<br/>` (in case of the XML version).

Comment: DOMDocument is not a string manipulator but an XML parser - once you've loaded your "raw" HTML into it, it no longer exists in the original form so whatever code you get out (e.g. `saveXML()`) is the code that PHP generates.

Comment: It's a bad notice. Do you know some alternative on PHP to do that (native, maybe), without need use some full parser package?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in a hacky but reliable way. PHP has the equivalent of `outerHTML` by passing the node to its parent document's `saveHTML()` method. Because this output is well-formed and escaped, you can easily strip the single outer tag from the text, leaving the desired `innerHTTML`.

Example:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div><p with="scary<>\'&quot;" attrs=40 ok>Hello <em>World</em></div>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//p') as $p) {
    $innerHTML = preg_replace('@^<([^>\\s]+)[^>]*>(.*)</\\1>$@s', '$2', $dom->saveHTML($p));
    var_dump($p);
}
```

Demo of regex: https://regex101.com/r/yEVMQx/2

Note the `s` flag on the regex is critical.